# Unable to open Anaconda navigator (stops at loading applications.. but never open.) in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: anaconda

The error log is the following:

```
(base) keerthi@kvardhan:~$ anaconda-navigator 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/keerthi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 550, in setup
    self.post_setup(conda_data=conda_data)
  File "/home/keerthi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 587, in post_setup
    self.tab_home.setup(conda_data)
  File "/home/keerthi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tabs/home.py", line 171, in setup
    self.set_applications(applications, packages)
  File "/home/keerthi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tabs/home.py", line 206, in set_applications
    apps = self.api.process_apps(applications, prefix=self.current_prefix)
  File "/home/keerthi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 865, in process_apps
    app = app(config=self.config, process_api=self._process_api)
  File "/home/keerthi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/pycharm.py", line 111, in __init__
    super(PyCharmProApp, self).__init__(
  File "/home/keerthi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/pycharm.py", line 15, in __init__
    super(BasePyCharmApp, self).__init__(
  File "/home/keerthi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/base.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.set_up_app_directory_path()
  File "/home/keerthi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/base.py", line 59, in set_up_app_directory_path
    self.app_directory_path = self._get_linux_installation_directory()
  File "/home/keerthi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/pycharm.py", line 62, in _get_linux_installation_directory
    for dir_name in os.listdir(root):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt'
```

I had tried everything
whether remove or install again or update or reset. All options i had tried. Earlier day i was able to open, but when i installed opera after that anaconda navigator is not working.
But I am able to open jupyter notebook, spyder, not anaconda navigator.
I requesting the help by getting answer from any of you.
With regards.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue in pop os looks like the location of the root directory specified is incorrect. all u have to do is open '/home/keerthi/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/pycharm.py' with gedit than go to line 54 and replace "root_dirs = ['/opt']" with "root_dirs = ['/']" and save the file.